# $http return response - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to create service in AngularJS to return the response of HTTP requests. My problem is the asynchronous request, because after I've submitted the request, my function returns `undefined` instantly and does not return the response from the server.

```
app.service('TesteService', function($http) {    

    this.teste = function(data) {
        var data = "*";

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'teste-s.php',
            params: {data: "bem recebido"}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            data = response.data;
            alert(data);
            return data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            data = "500";
        });
    }
});
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use callbacks or promises.

Comment: Read https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/